# Binary Elliptic Curves Point Doubling Formula - Calculate Lambda from P3

Tags: elliptic-curves, finite-field, elliptic-curve-generation

As I am studying ordinary (non-supersingular) binary elliptic curves in the Guide to ECC book by Hankerson (Section 3.1, page 81), for point doubling, the equations presented in the book are:

$x_3 = \lambda^2 + \lambda + a = {x_1}^2 + \frac{b}{{x_1}^2}$

$y_3 = {x_1}^2 + (\lambda + 1) x_3 $

$\lambda = x_1 + y_1/x_1$

I have some questions to confirm my understanding, and I really appreciate elaboration on this:

1. To my understanding, $\lambda$ is a gradient. Then, if I have the information about the result of point doubling (i.e., $x_3, y_3$), can I calculate $\lambda$ as $\lambda = x_3 + y_3/x_3$ instead of $\lambda = x_1 + y_1/x_1$? Or isn't it possible, and I should use other equations (like point halving? But I can not find the formula in the book).
2. Unrelated to the above question, the value of $a$ and $b$ is always known, right? So for calculating $x_3$, I can use either $\lambda^2 + \lambda + a$ or ${x_1}^2 + \frac{b}{{x_1}^2}$ and it will always be correct. Is that true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. One can think of $\lambda$ as the (formal) gradient of the tangent to the curve at the point $(x_1,y_1)$, but this will not be the same as the gradient of the tangent to the curve at the point $(x_3,y_3)$. You should instead use the formulae for point halving (see pages 7-8 of [this paper by Pornin](https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/1325.pdf) for example).
2. Yes, that is correct. To see the equivalence note that by the curve equation
   $$y_1^2=x_1y_1+x_1^3+ax_1^2+b$$
   so that
   $$\lambda^2=x_1^2+\frac{y_1^2}{x_1^2}=x_1^2+\frac{y_1}{x_1}+x_1+a+\frac b{x_1^2}$$
   and
   $$\lambda^2+\lambda+a=\left(x_1^2+\frac{y_1}{x_1}+x_1+a+\frac b{x_1^2}\right)+\left(x_1+\frac{y_1}{x_1}\right)+a=x_1^2+\frac b{x_1^2}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I will look into that. One question, just realized I have come across the paper previously, but I thought that the paper was not very "authoritative" because the equation for Point Doubling is slightly different (i.e., $y_3 = \lambda (x_1 + x_3) + x_3 + y_1$) than Hankerson's (see Page 7 about Point Addition (and point doubling)). It looks like a point addition equation to me. Would you say that the paper is a good reference to study binary elliptic curves?

Comment: I am happy to endorse the Pornin paper as an good reference for the study of binary elliptic curves. The different form of the addition equation again follows from straightforward identities.

Comment: Then, does it mean I can use the above equation interchangeably with Hankerson's, right?
Thank you very much for your explanation! I was afraid that the Point Doubling will have different characteristics so that I can't use $y_1$ for that.

Comment: @prairie99: I second the recommendation for the Pornin paper when the goal is efficiency and constant-timeness (that's independently of The Bear being our [user#28](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/28)). [update] The formulas page 7 should be OK (it's only later that the paper proposes a coordinate system that I think is new, and definitely leads to formulas different from the formulas for Cartesian coordinates).